# How to inject EntityManager into a RabbitMQBundle consumer

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

I have followed the documentation [here](http://hipaway.com/blog/asynchronous-processing-with-symfony2-and-rabbitmq/) to create a RabbitMQ consumer, however, I need to be able to use the Doctrine `EntityManager` in my consumer, and I am at a loss as to how to do this.

As it is a command, I tried to extend `ConainerAwareCommand` however, the execute method signature for a consumer is incompatible with this type.  I have found no obvious way to override the constructor and/or call a setter to no avail, even if I create it as a service.

Has anyone else got any experience with how to do this?

EDIT:

I have already tried creating this as a service, and have the following services.yml:

```
import.video:
    class:  Acme\DemoBundle\Service\Consumer\ImportVideoConsumer
    arguments:
        entityManager: @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

And the consumer looks like this:

```
class ImportVideoConsumer implements ConsumerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityMagager;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        var_dump($entityManager);
    }

    /**
     * Process the message
     *
     * @param AMQPMessage $msg
     */
    public function execute(AMQPMessage $msg)
    {
        $body = json_decode($msg->body);
        var_dump($this->entityMagager);
    }
}
```

When I `var_dump()` in the constructor I can see that the object is instantiated correctly, however when I `var_dump()` in the execute method the entityManager property is NULL.  Is it possible that the class is being instantiated once for the container, but the instance that is passed in to the command is not instantiated through the service container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the service you need to inject is `doctrine.orm.entity_manager`.

---

Because I am sooo cool, here is an example of an `emailConsumer` where we inject both a mailer and the entityManager:

**If you use YML:**

```
services:
  acme_demo.consumer.email:
    class:  Acme\DemoBundle\Consumer\EmailConsumer
    arguments: 
        mailer: "@mailer"
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

**If you use XML:**

```
    <service id="acme_demo.consumer.email" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Consumer\EmailConsumer">
        <argument type="service" id="mailer" />
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
    </service>
```

**In your consumer:**

```
class EmailConsumer implements ConsumerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Swift_Mailer
     */
    private $mailer;

    /**
     * @var EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, $entityManager){

        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->em = $entityManager;

    }

    public function execute(AMQPMessage $msg)
    {
        //Your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my further elaboration to me question - I have tried creating this as a service, but the EntityManager never seems to get assigned correctly.

Comment: You have a typo in your code, it's $entityManager in your property, not $entityMagager. Same error in the var_dump() too :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever encouter "There is no active transaction" exception when using Doctrine in a consumer? I have a consumer that runs as a background process and after a couple of hours, I've got this error message. Therefore I have to relaunch the consumer manually.